# Getting wrong values trying to convert to a latitude longitude system

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, proj

By using listgeo I got the following information:

```
PCS = 31468 (name unknown)
```

If I am not mistaken this translates to `DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4`, and by using [this](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31468/) site I got a proj4 string:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs
```

Trying to convert values drom this projection system to *latlong* using proj4, I am doing the following:

```
double x1, y1;
x1 = 4386596.4101;
y1 = 5237914.5325;

pj_merc = pj_init_plus("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs")

pj_latlong = pj_init_plus("+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84")

pj_transform(pj_merc, pj_latlong, 1, 1, &x1, &y1, NULL )
```

What I get back though is **0.226465 0.917617**.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If I try units = degrees then the initialization actually fails though.

Comment: Could it be this: https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/pj_transform  `Note that geographic locations need to be passed in radians, not decimal degrees, and will be returned similarly`

Comment: Using `x1 *= DEG_TO_RAD; y1 *= DEG_TO_RAD;` on my original coordinates gives something like `-0.433622 0.0128923`. That again is not correct.

Comment: Is the result from gdaltranform correct: `gdaltransform -s_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +
x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=latlong +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"
4386596 5237914
10.4999289039683 47.270013810372 53.9770113388076`

Comment: I am using the proj4 library that I compiled. I do not have gdal. Let me give it a try though.

Comment: Are you sure the command is correct. Because I get a -too many command options- error.

Comment: This comment window if not perfect for chat like this. Hit Enter after +datum=WGS84". An empty line appears, feed the coordinates and hit Enter again.

Comment: No according to Global mapper the results of the command above are not correct.

Comment: Result is the same with EPSG codes `gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:31468 -t_srs epsg:4326 
4386596 5237914
10.4999289039683 47.270013810372 53.9770113388076` Are you sure that 31468 is correct? But anyway your code should give the same result than gdaltransform and cs2cs except in radians. I can't say why it does not.

Comment: Yes PCS is indeed 31268. I have no idea actually, from the little documentation that proj4 has what I wrote should work unless there is an issue with my projection system.

Comment: What is the result from Global Mapper? Can you check the parameters of 31268 used be Global Mapper? What does gdalinfo report about your GeoTIFF? Result from gdaltransform as radians is 0.183258 0.825017 with my deg->rad converter.

Comment: gdalinfo reports that my projection system is `DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4` `UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]` `PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",12],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",4500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,`

Comment: In g. mapper I am trying to transform from `Gauss Krueger (3 degree zones)
DATUM: POTSDAM/DHDN (GERMANY)
UNIT: meters
ZONE:  (4)` to `Geographic (Latitude/Longitude)
DATUM: WGS84
UNIT: arc degrees
CENTRAL LONGITUDE:    0.000000`

Comment: Maybe you could summarise this information that is all lost in the comments back into the question?

Comment: @BradHards there is no need for that anymore, because I found a solution. Probably anyone that comes here would just be interested in that. Do have a look though, in case I am wrong.

Comment: EPSG:31268 has a false Easting of 8500000. That does not fit at all to your coordinates, while 31468 might be near Gramais in Austria.

Comment: I used the values as they were reported by gdal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my proj4 strings are correct, what was left was only some kind of mistake with my unit types. After having a look as to what units does each system use I believe that transforming your final data from *rads* to *degrees* should solve the issue.

Comment: `"+proj=latlong +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m"` has definitely the wrong units. latlong is always in degrees, while tmerc always needs meters.

Comment: Forgot to edit that part, in the question.